# Vimeo API for private videos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vimeo

I need to develop an application which can embed videos or lives, only for certain users.
Those videos/lives should be hosted on Vimeo.
Question is if Vimeo API supports embedding private videos through an Authorization Flow, without letting the users sign in to Vimeo from my app.

In essence, my backend should have a token which can access to those private videos and embed them only if users meet the requirements.

Does Vimeo API allows something like that? If yes, what would be the correct procedure?
I couldn't find anything like that in their docs, at least with no oAuth2 procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vimeo Help Center has an answer for you: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042878091-Custom-video-privacy-overriding-privacy-settings-using-the-API

> The API can toggle a video’s privacy settings, but it cannot be used
>   to allow video playback outside of the privacy settings we provide.
>   For example, you can use the API to set a video as password-protected
>   and set the video's password, however, you cannot use the API to
>   authenticate and bypass password protection and allow playback.

The video privacy settings that can be assigned using the API are described here: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224817847-Privacy-settings-overview

Comment: Thank you, so i were right unfortunately. Do you think there is a way to let the Video private (maybe only via URL, so "unlinsted"), get the stream of the video on my backend and send it to the HTML player? This way i won't leave the URL in my front-end code and only the backend will know the correct URL

Comment: did you ever find an answer/solution to that? I did find a way of using an unlisted video and restricted embedding to certain domains. still a token based auth system would be preferential.